# Google Cloud Messaging app for iOS

Tags: ios, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use "Google Cloud Messaging" service in my existing iOS app but first i want to try on an tets app. I am trying to get register with GCM for Notifications. I have generated P12 files from apple developer account and than got the **"GoogleServices-Info.plist"** configuration file from google. I am following this link [**https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start**](http://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/start) , here first point is that get our sample project but i don't know that where i have to get the sample project and when i create my own new project and run this command **"pod try google"** is giving error that **Unable to find a specification for `google`**. Please help me in this regard.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's `pod try Google` (with a capital G).

Comment: Thanks alot user102008